# Customize node.js start command with AWS Opsworks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

What is the best way to get Opsworks to use the command `NODE_ENV=production node server.js` to start the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Best Solution :** Use Environment Values in Chef 11.10 stack. [Opsworks Environment Variables Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-creating.html#workingapps-creating-environment)

Alternative:

This is not currently supported as an environment option by default. So you will need to add it in.

I will assume you are using latest Chef 11.4 cookbooks .

modify ( LINE 2 of ) :

```
opsworks_nodejs/templates/default/node_web_app.monitrc.erb
```

FROM :

```
start program = "/bin/sh -c 'cd <%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current; /usr/bin/env NODE_PATH=<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current/node_modules:<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current /usr/local/bin/node <%= @monitored_script %>'"
```

TO :

```
start program = "/bin/sh -c 'cd <%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current; /usr/bin/env NODE_PATH=<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current/node_modules:<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current NODE_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/node <%= @monitored_script %>'"
```

I made a set of changes to the official cookbook, and did a pull request to add this into the official one. If you want to - you can have a look at the changes : https://github.com/nappa32/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/add_support_for_node_env_for_expre